# Docker debian slow dns resolve

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, debian, response-time

I got terribly slow dns resolve inside my `ubuntu` when using `wget` or `curl`, `apt-get`,...

```
root@815340a37f0e:/# time curl www.google.com
...
real    0m5.132s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.003s
```

When I do `nslookup` its pretty fast.

```
root@815340a37f0e:/# time nslookup google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.78.101
...
real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the DNS which is slow and not something else? Perhaps the MTU is wrong and causes your TCP traffic being much slower than it should be? Capture the traffic with tcpdump or wireshark and see how it goes.

Comment: When I run `wget google.com`, `Resolving google.com (google.com)...` gets printed out and whole process waits like 5 seconds. After that `Resolving google.com (google.com)... 74.125.71.139, 74.125.71.113, 74.125.71.138, ...` IP addresses are appended and whole is instantly finished. So I guess problem is at the resolving stage.

Comment: What is in the container's `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton `nameserver 8.8.8.8`
I installed dnsmasq so lookups are cached atleast. Isn't 5seconds resolution time against `8.8.8.8` normal?

Comment: how long is it taking when you try `curl` with google's IP address like `time curl -L 173.194.78.101` and can you also provide the output of `ping 173.194.78.101`.

Comment: resolving when curling and wgeting takes same time (~5seconds). Ping or nslookup are like instant (few milis).

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem, and we found out [that our hardware showed broken behaviour with IPv6.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4)

You could double check with `curl` and force IPv4 like so:

```
$ time curl -4 www.google.com
...
real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**Update 1:**

We had the problem with our Windows Host System (Ubuntu 14.04 is the guest). The actual solution was found on [this page.](http://robert.penz.name/902/slow-dns-resolving-with-linux-systems-against-windows-dns-server/)

Adding `options single-request-reopen` to the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and running `sudo resolvconf -h` did the trick for us.

I found another anwser on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/32312/57396) that suggested almost the same.